# Generate a series of line in every mouseclick in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphic

i have a problem with my java gui :( I hope you will help me :)

I have a black gui, when I click with the mouse in the gui, the programm save the coordinates of that click in a Point previous. Then, when i click on a second place, the programm save the second's click coordinates in the Point current and draw a Line beetween "previous" and "current".

But now i want that when i click for the third time in the gui, the programm will draw a line beetween the second click and the third click and so on.
The fourth beetween the fifth.

How can i do it?

This is my code:

```
 public class OdometerPanel extends JPanel {
    private double totalDistance;
    private Point previous = null, current = null;
    private ArrayList<Point> travelledPoints;
    private int p1x, p2x, p1y, p2y;
    private double distance;
    JLabel pointco = new JLabel("");
    JLabel trav = new JLabel("Travelled Distance: " + distance);

public OdometerPanel() {
  LineListener listener = new LineListener();
  addMouseListener(listener);
  addMouseMotionListener(listener);

  trav.setForeground(Color.green);
  pointco.setForeground(Color.yellow);
  add(pointco);
  add(trav);
  setBackground(Color.black);
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
  {
      super.paintComponent(page);

    page.setColor (Color.yellow);
    if (previous != null && current != null)
     page.drawLine(previous.x, previous.y, current.x, current.y);
  }


  private class LineListener implements MouseListener,
                                     MouseMotionListener
   {
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
  {        

      if(previous == null && current == null) {
     previous = event.getPoint();
      p1x = (int) previous.getX();
      p1y = (int) previous.getY();
      pointco.setText("P(" + p1x + "," + p1y + ")");
      }
      else {
          current = event.getPoint();
          p2x = (int) current.getX();
          p2y = (int) current.getY();
          distance = (int) Math.sqrt((p2x - p1x)*(p2x - p1x) + (p2y - p1y) * (p2y - p1y));
          trav.setText("Travelled Distance: " + distance);
          pointco.setText("P(" + p2x + "," + p2y + ")");
          repaint(); 
      }

   }

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {}       
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance :D``

Comment: `if(previous == null && current == null)` This will never be true after the first time the method is called, so `previous` will never have its value changed again

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `mouseClicked` code should be more along these lines.

```
if(current == null) {
    current = event.getPoint();
    p1x = (int) current.getX(); p1y = (int) current.getY();
    pointco.setText("P(" + p1x + "," + p1y + ")");
} else {
    previous = current;
    current = event.getPoint();
    p1x = (int) previous.getX();
    p1y = (int) previous.getY();
    p2x = (int) current.getX();
    p2y = (int) current.getY();
    distance = (int) Math.sqrt((p2x - p1x)*(p2x - p1x) + (p2y - p1y) * (p2y - p1y));
    trav.setText("Travelled Distance: " + distance);
    pointco.setText("P(" + p2x + "," + p2y + ")");
    repaint();
}
```

Not sure if `previous = current` will actually work. You may need something more like

```
previous = new Point(current.getX(), current.getY());
```

It depends on what constructors are available for the Point class.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you wanted multiple lines drawn at the same time which means you would need to keep a list of all the points.

In main class:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
    super.paintComponent(page);

    page.setColor(Color.yellow);

    for(int i= 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point p1 = points.get(i-1);
        Point p2 = points.get(i);
        page.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    }
}
```

In MouseListener

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    points.add(event.getPoint());
}
```